# Inverse of Quadratics with Horizontal Transformations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics, inverse, inverse-function

This might sound like a beginner question for a lot of the community, I apologize, but, I really need help understanding it. I was trying to find the inverse of the quadratic $ f(x)= (\frac 12x +2)^2 +4$. Using WolframAlpha, I was able to find that the inverse function was $ f(x) = ±  2 \sqrt{x - 4}-4$

My steps are the following;

$y=(\frac 12x +2)^2 +4$

$x=(\frac 12y +2)^2 +4$

$x-4=(\frac 12y +2)^2$

$ \sqrt{x-4} =\frac 12y +2$

$ \sqrt{x-4} -2 =\frac 12y$

$ 2\sqrt{x-4} -2 =y$

I don't understand why I am getting a different inverse equation than the original.

Comment: in line 4 you are not putting in $\pm$ and in line 6 your are forgetting to multiply 2 by 2

Comment: Two things to note: The square root of (y/2 + 2)^2 is |y/2 + 2| which is what gives you the plus/minus sign before the square root.

Comment: The other thing to note is that when, in your last step, you multiply both sides by 2, you forgot that the left is the sum of two terms, so both of them should get multiplied by 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=(\frac 12x +2)^2 +4$

$x=(\frac 12y +2)^2 +4$

$x-4=(\frac 12y +2)^2$

Everything is right up to here.

$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, so you need a $\pm$ in front of the square root, because you need to account for both positive and negative values of $y$ for a given $x$ while solving for the inverse.

$\pm \sqrt{x-4} =\frac 12y +2$

$\pm \sqrt{x-4} -2 =\frac 12y$

You need to multiply both sides by $2$ (above, you only multiplied $\sqrt{x-4}$ by $2$, but not the $-2$).

Final answer: $y = \pm 2\sqrt{x-4} - 4 $

Comment: Thanks! That cleared up a lot of misunderstanding about inverse of quadratics for me.